# Порядок сборки Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, зависимости, dockerfile

В Dockerfile часто сначала копируются файлы зависимостей (gemfile/package.json и тд), а затем устанавливаются зависимости. Затем копируется все приложение.

Почему не рекомендуется просто скопировать всю папку и установить зависимости?

Comment: Сначала система, потом пакеты, потом уже по сути "статика" выливается. Я не эксперт, но, имхо, вполне логичное действие. Я еще до проекта копирую всякие nginx'овые штуки, например. Кстати, вопрос и правда интересный, я даже не задумывался и не пробовал иное...

Comment: *Почему не рекомендуется просто скопировать всю папку и установить зависимости?* — этот вопрос следует задать тому, кто что-то там «не рекомендует».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Мне периодически приходится "упаковывать" rails-приложения в docker-образы и некоторые моменты для себя отметил.

Отвечая на вопрос:

> Почему не рекомендуется просто скопировать всю папку и установить
>   зависимости?

Полагаю, потому что сборка образа будет не такая быстрая как могла бы быть.

Допустим, что после сборки docker-образа c Вашим приложением Вам требуется продолжать доработку этого приложения и проверку работы его в образе.

Если в Вашем Dockerfile будет что-то типа:

```
...
COPY . /app/folder
RUN bundle install
```

то при каждой корректировке любого файла, docker будет копировать файлы и устанавливать зависимости заново. Это занимает много времени.

А если Вы напишите так:

```
COPY Gemfile* /app/folder
RUN bundle install
...
COPY . /app/folder
```

то зависимости условно будут уже "установлены" и сборка образа пройдет быстрее.

Можно еще ускорить сборку образа путем "пакетирования" зависимостей rails-приложения

```
bundle package
```

Гемы будут уложены в директорию */vendor/cache* и в Dockerfile тогда можно записать так:

```
COPY Gemfile* /app/folder
COPY vendor/cache ./vendor/cache
RUN bundle install --local
...
COPY . /app/folder
```

При частых доработках проекта подобная конфигурация, по моему мнению, может существенно сократить время на сборку образов.

Comment: Никогда ничего не "пакетируйте". Если нужно ускорить - разбейте на несколько образов. Набор гемов меняется не так часто. Гемы должны устанавливаться в Docker окружении. Когда нужно будет работать с разными версиями Ruby одновременно никакой RVM не поможет.  Кеш гемов отлично работает с Capistrano, но для docker этого не нужно.